# issue with random input latency on quest 3

Tags: audio, virtual-reality, latency, oculus, quest

We have an app that works fine on quest 2.
On quest 3 we have sync issues.
The feature is recording audio along with existing audio (and it syncs it that playback plays back same as recording)

what could be different about quest 3 in this regard?

Thank for any clue , cheers